# How to add Custom Logo / .jpg file in Angular5 Ag-Grid export to excel in Header

Tags: c#, angular, export-to-excel

I am trying to add a log in exported excel sheet, which is coming from Ag-Grid, export to excel functionality.I am not getting how to add the .jpg logo file in the custom header, while calling export ,it should include logo in Excel sheet.i am using enterprise version of Ag grid.
thanks.......